# How can I solve 'Handle bad layers' error when using OpenStreetMap in Qgis?

Tags: qgis

I can easy download Portion of maps from OpenStreetMap, save them etc. Once I reopen the same map I get a message that says "Handle bad layers" for all the OSM files.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hello and welcome to GIS.SE, could you improve your question and explain how you are open the maps? Which software are you using, which steps to reproduce this behaviour, etc.?

Comment: I use Qgis 1.8.0 Lisboa. I have 5 layers of Shp files. I wish to add from Openstreet sections of Indiana map.  I downloaded OSM inside QGIS and saved the file. Once reopened I got Handlebadlayers for all OSM files. If I understood well the only way to keep these information is to convert the OSM file to SHP file, at least this worked for me, but I'll be glad if it exists a easier way to do that, since I have to convert each layer, points, lines, polygons, separately, but doing this I loose the original style from OSM. If somebody can show me a better workflow to rich my goal is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You get the "Handle bad layers" dialogue because the Openstreetmap plugin stores the data in a temporary database, which will be destroyed when exiting the current QGIS session.

The "old" Openstreetmap plugin in QGIS Lisboa has some limitations, and a new version for QGIS 2.0 is already on the way. You just have to wait a bit on that. This might also help on your styling problem.