# How to resolve error "Handle bad layers" in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers

I'm new to QGIS and have been seeing what it can do for me – seems good. I imported shape file data from a UK Ordnance Survey data file and saved the file in a new folder. It was very good, doing all I wanted. I exported and got exactly what I wanted ( a tiff image).

I closed the file in order to try a new experiment. When I went to re-open it I got a dialogue box saying 'Handle Bad Layers. I don't understand what is at issue and what to do.

Comment: http://www.screenr.com/gkvs has a screencast that might help you - usually the reference to the source file is broken

Comment: try here some similar answers for your question http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63715/how-can-i-solve-handle-bad-layers-error-when-using-openstreetmap-in-qgis

Answer (score 2):

The bad layer error is an information that some datasets cannot be found at their path (which is specified in the project file).

From your description, you probably create some files while experimenting. Maybe some temporary ones, which have been deleted in the meantime.

If you can provide more information, we can go into more detail.